# Laravel Nginx rewrite

Tags: laravel, nginx, url-rewriting

If user enters
http://www.example.com
or
http://www.example.com/

I want Nginx to launch
/home/forge/default/public/index.html
or
/home/forge/default/public/index.htm

If user enters
http://www.example.com/x
or
http://www.example.com/welcome
or
http://www.example.com/user/6

I want Nginx to launch Laravel index.php with query_string at the end
/home/forge/default/public/laravelproject/public/index.php

I tried this and it does not work.

```
server {

    server_name default;
    root /home/forge/default/public;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location ~ ^/(.+)$ {
      rewrite ^/(.+)$ /$1 last;
      try_files $uri/laravelproject/public/index.php?$query_string;
    }


    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do this? You can just set the laravel "/" route to serve index.html

Comment: Because if user requests "http://www.example.com" or "http://www.example.com/" I want to serve just static content from root "/home/forge/default/public" - not php involved.

Comment: You're allowed to do that and still serve it via Laravel.

Comment: The point is I dont want to serve static content with Laravel. I would have to invoke "/home/forge/default/public/laravelproject/public/index.php" so that means php is involved.

Comment: What you're proposing of doing is bad practice. If you're going to use Laravel use Laravel all the way, don't try to hack around it for something that will offer no real improvement.

Comment: Thanks apokryfos. Anybody else knows how to do it?
I dont want to use Laravel all the way. Predominantly I will have just static content.